# On the sparse subset sum problem

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In Gentry's [seminal paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/1536414.1536440) on fully homomorphic encryption (FHE), it is assumed that the **sparse subset set problem** is hard. It looks like there is a [followup paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/567.pdf) on the concrete parameter of the **subset size**, which mentions that Gentry's choice of subset size is too aggressive (e.g., 15). However, in its section 5 (Discussion), it also mentioned that the real assumption used Gentry's paper is the **hidden** sparse subset problem and its analysis does not apply.

So, regarding the choice of  subset size, what is regarded as a "safe" parameter for the hidden sparse subset problem right now? E.g., given the size of the entire set of weights be 32k used in Gentry's paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been stronger attacks against Gentry's FHE scheme, in particular I believe the 2016 work of Biasse + Song (quantumly) breaks it in polynomial time (and classically in sub-exponential time). Given this relative weakness compared to other FHE schemes, I have not seen people try to concretely instantiate Gentry's work (say in the last ~5 years --- of course there was early work along these lines).

Discussion of this can be found in Bernstein's work, for example [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1428.pdf). In general, if you are worrying about concrete parameter sizes for FHE implementations, I would direct you to the [Homomorphic Encryption Standard](https://homomorphicencryption.org/standard/). It does not include Gentry's scheme, likely due to the aforementioned attacks.
This is to explicitly say that it is unclear if there is a "safe" parameterization cryptographers would agree on --- most try to work with the standard problems of LWE/SIS (and their algebraic variants) now instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information!